# Are there convenient tools to automatically check C++ coding conventions beyond style checks?

Tags: c++, static-analysis

Are there good tools to automatically check C++ projects for coding conventions like e.g.:

*all thrown objects have to be classes derived from std::exception (i.e. `throw 42;` or `throw "runtime error";` would be flagged as errors, just like `throw std::string("another runtime error");` or throwing any other type not derived from std::exception)*

In the end I'm looking for something like [Cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/) but with a simpler way to add new checks than hacking the source code of the check tool... May be even something with a nice little GUI which allows you to set up the rules, write them to disk and use the rule set in an IDE like Eclipse or an continuous integration server like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

Comment: Probably want to keep an eye on the C++ Core Guidelines: https://isocpp.org/blog/2015/09/bjarne-stroustrup-announces-cpp-core-guidelines

Comment: voting to close as tool rec

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key problem with "style checkers" is that style is like art: everybody has a different opinion about what is good style and what is not.   The implication is that style checkers will always need to be customized to the local art tastes.

To do this right, one needs a full C++ parser with access to symbol definitions, scoping rules and ideally various kinds of flow analyses.   AFAIK, CppCheck does not provide accurate parsing or symbol table definitions, so its error checking can't be both deep and correct.   I think Coverity and Fortify offer something along these lines using the EDG front end; I don't know  if their tools offer access to symbol tables or data flow analyses. Clang is coming along.

You also need a way to write the style checks.  I think all the tools offer access to an AST and perhaps symbol tables, and you can hand code your own checks, at the cost of knowing the AST intimately, which is hard for a big language like C++.   I think Coverity and Fortify have some DSL-like scheme for specifying some of the checks.

If you want to *fix* code that is style incorrect, you need something that can modify the code representation.   Coverity and Fortify do not offer this AFAIK.   I believe Clang does offer the ability to modify the AST and regenerate code; you still have to have pretty intimate knowledge of the AST structure to code the tree hacking logic and get it right.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) and its [C++ front end](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CppFrontEnd.html) provide most of these capabilities.  Using its C++ front end, DMS can parse ANSI C++11, GCC4 (with C++11 extensions) and MSVS 2010 (with its C++11 extensions) [update May 2021: now full C++17 and most of C++20] build ASTs and symbol tables with full type information. One can also ask for the type of an arbitrary expression AST node.  At present, DMS computes control flow but not data flow for C++.

An AST API lets you procedurally code arbitrary checks; or make changes to the AST to fix problems, and then DMS's prettyprinter can regenerate complete, compilable source text with comments and preserved literal format information (eg., radix of numbers, etc.).  You have to know the AST structure to do this, just like other tools, but it is a lot easier to know, because it is isomorphic to the DMS C++ grammar rules.   The C++ front end comes with the our C++ grammar.   [DMS uses GLR parsers to make this possible].

In addition, one can write patterns and transformations using DMS's Rule Specification Language, using the surface syntax of C++ itself.  One might code OPs  "dont throw nonSTL exceptions" as

```
 pattern nonSTLexception(i: IDENTIFIER):statement
   = " throw \i; " if ~derived_from_STD_exception(i);
```

The stuff inside the (meta)quotes is C++ source code with some pattern-matching escapes, e.g, "\i" refers to the placeholder varible "i" which must be a C++ IDENTIFIER according the rule; the entire "throw \i;" clause must be a C++ "statement" (a nonterminal in the C++ grammar).  The rule itself mainly expresses syntax to be matched, but can invoke semantic checks (such as "~is_derived_from_STD_exception") applied to matched subtrees (in this case, whatever "\i" matched).

In writing such patterns, you don't have to know the shape of the AST; the pattern knows it, and it is automatically matched.  If you've ever coded AST walkers, you will appreciate how convenient this is.

A match knows the AST node and therefore the precision position (file/line/column) which makes it easy to generate reports with precise location information.

You need to add a custom routine to DMS, "inherits_from_STD_exception", to verify the identifier tree node passed to that routine is (as OP desired) a class derived from
std::exception.  This requires finding "std::exception" in the symbol table,
and verifying that the symbol table entry for the identifier tree node is a class
declaration and transitively inherits from other class declarations (by following symbol table links) until the std::exception symbol table entry is found.

A DMS transformation rule is a pair of patterns stating in essence, "if you see *this*, then replace it by *that*".

We've built several custom style checkers with DMS for both COBOL and C++.   Its still a fair amount of work, mostly because C++ is a pretty complex language and you have to think carefully about the precise meaning of your check.

Trickier checks and those tests that start to fall into deep static analysis require access to control and data flow information.  DMS computes control flow for C++ now, and we're working on data flow analysis (we've already done this for Java, IBM Enterprise COBOL and a variety of C dialects).  Analysis results are tied back to the AST nodes so that one can use patterns to look for elements of the style check, and then follow the data flows to tie the elements together if needed.

When all is said and done with DMS, (or indeed with any of the other tools that deal with C++ in any halfway accurate way), is that coding additional or complex style checks is unlikely to be "convenient".   You should hope for "possible with good technical background."

Answer (score 10):

I ran a number of static analysis tools on my current project and here are some of the key takeaways:

- I used [Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint) as a single entry point for running all these tools. VL is a plug-in for VS to run third-party static analysis tools and allows a single click route from the report to the source code. Apart from supporting a GUI for selecting between the different levels of errors reported it also provides automated background analysis (that tells you how many errors have been fixed as you go), manual analysis for a single file, color coded error displays and charting facility. The VL installer is pretty spiffy and extremely helpful when you're trying to add new static analysis tools (it even helps you download Python from ActiveState should you want to use Google cpplint and don't have Python pre-installed!). You can learn more about VL here: http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/features.html
- Of the numerous tools that can be run with VL, I chose three that work with native C++ code: cppcheck, Google cpplint and Inspirel Vera++. These tools have different capabilities.
- Cppcheck: This is probably the most common one and we have all used it. So, I'll gloss over the details. Suffice to say that it catches errors such as using postfix increment for non-primitive types, warns about using size() when empty() should be used, scope reduction of variables, incorrect name qualification of members in class definition, incorrect initialization order of class members, missing initializations, unused variables, etc. For our codebase cppcheck reported about 6K errors. There were a few false positives (such as unused function) but these were suppresed. You can learn more about cppcheck here: http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf
- [Google cpplint](http://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/): This is a python based tool that checks your source for style violations. The style guide against which this validation is done can be found here: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cppguide.xml (which is basically Google's C++ style guide). Cpplint produced ~ 104K errors with our codebase of which most errors are related to whitespaces (missing or extra), tabs, brace position etc. A few that are probably worth fixing are: C-style casts, missing headers.
- [Inspirel Vera++](http://www.inspirel.com/vera): This is a programmable tool for verification, analysis and transformation of C++ source code. This is similar to cpplint in functionality. A list of the available rules can be found here: http://www.inspirel.com/vera/ce/doc/rules/index.html and a similar list of available transformations can be found here: http://www.inspirel.com/vera/ce/doc/transformations/index.html. Details on how to add your own rule can be found here: http://www.inspirel.com/vera/ce/doc/tclapi.html. For our project, Vera++ found about 90K issues (for the 20 odd rules).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed feedback! Nevertheless, except for Vera++ non of them seem to allow custom rules and from a quick look at Vera++ it seems to be more of a style tool an not capable to identify class hierarchies and similar concepts

Comment: @g_daniel: I have been in your shoes and not have had much luck. I guess you could add rules to Vera akin to what Matthieu writes (in the other answer) but I didn't get around to try it out. I wish I could help you more :/

Comment: Also note that a version of `cpplint` is hosted on PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cpplint  It can be installed simply by: `pip install cpplint`

Answer (score 6):

In the *upcoming* state: Manuel Klimek, from Google, is integrating in the Clang mainline a tool that has been developed at Google for querying and transforming C++ code.

- The tooling infrastructure has been layed out, it may fill up but it is already functional. The main idea is that it allows you to define actions and will run those actions on the selected files.
- Google has created a simple set of C++ classes and methods to allow querying the AST in a friendly way: the AST Matcher framework, it is being developped and will allow very precise matching in the end.

It requires creating an executable at the moment, but the code is provided as libraries so it's not necessary to edit it, and one-off transformation tools can be dealt with in a single source file.

---

Example of the Matcher ([found in this thread](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Fwd-Patch-AST-Matcher-Framwork-and-an-example-tool-td3016371.html)): the goal is to find calls to the constructor overload of `std::string` formed from the result of `std::string::c_str()` (with the default allocator), because it can be replaced by a simple copy instead.

```
ConstructorCall(
    HasDeclaration(Method(HasName(StringConstructor))),
    ArgumentCountIs(2),
    // The first argument must have the form x.c_str() or p->c_str()
    // where the method is string::c_str(). We can use the copy
    // constructor of string instead (or the compiler might share
    // the string object).
    HasArgument(
        0,
        Id("call", Call(
            Callee(Id("member", MemberExpression())),
            Callee(Method(HasName(StringCStrMethod))),
            On(Id("arg", Expression()))
        ))
    ),
    // The second argument is the alloc object which must not be
    // present explicitly.
    HasArgument(1, DefaultArgument())
)
```

It is very promising compared to ad-hoc tool because it uses the Clang compiler AST library, so not only it is guaranteed that no matter how complicated the macros and template stuff that are used, as long as your code compiles it can be analyzed; but it also means that intricates queries that depend on the result of overload resolution can be expressed.

This code returns actual AST nodes from within the Clang library, so the programmer can locate the bits and nits precisely in the source file and edit to tweak it according to her needs.

There has been talk about using a textual matching specification, however it was deemed better to start with the C++ API as it would have added much complexity (and bike-shedding). I hope a Python API will emerge.

Comment: I hoped that someone would come up with something based on llvm! I found only the [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) when searching the web for something like that and unfortunately this project didn't seem very flexible with respect to custom rules. This AST Matcher Framwork sounds very promising and as long as the C++ API is as nice as the given example, there is no need for a special config file syntax :-)

Comment: @g_daniel: you are right that the static analyzer is not customizable. In the past I think a few style rules made it into it (for lack of a better tool), but in the end it is more a tool to reason about safety issues (memory overwrite, etc...). I am not sure whether the AST Matcher would be suitable for style analysis, I see it more as a C++ aware version of `grep` and `sed` :)

Comment: I'm not looking for style analyzers, but for analyzers of coding conventions beyond style ;-) i.e. for coding conventions like "don't use std::auto_ptr, use std::shared_ptr" or "don't throw ints to indicate error codes, don't throw (C-)strings with error messages, throw proper exception classes derived from std::exception". I think the AST Matcher Framework would be great for implementing something like that. I'll wait a little longer to see if there are some already released alternatives. If there are none, I'll accept your answer ;-)

Comment: Im just wondering, if once this is released it will also work for C and not only C++, as these languages are very easy and the compiler come with support for both anyway.

Comment: @lanoxx: It should cover C, C++, Objective-C and Objective-C++. And actually I believe that C is already well-covered in the trunk version since it's much simpler.